# Is there a way to view the A-Frame inspector on mobile devices?

Tags: aframe

Is there a way to call the inspector programmatically?
On computers, there's the ctrl + alt  + I shortcut. But what about mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inspector UI is not designed for mobile devices. You can though open it up programmatically on any device but the experience wont be good on mobile:

```
  sceneEl.components.inspector.openInspector();
```

[Glitch illustrating](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/puzzling-curly-scraper?path=index.html%3A19%3A53)